# PHP Use multiple accounts for one MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a new website that does the following for account creation:

- First, it checks in the `users` table of the `Users` db if there is an account with that name
- Next, it `INSERT`s `name` into the `users` table
- Finally, using a different account, it creates a table named after the user, using a statement like: `CREATE TABLE $name LIKE template`

However, this creates some issues.  Occasionally, table creation fails, so I have a "ghost user" that lacks a table.  Ideally, I would have the account which accesses the User database be separate from the one which accesses the other db with all the tables.

How could I do this?  Could I have one account with permission ONLY to run stored procedures in both DBs?  If I did the last option, how could I guarantee completion of both tasks?  **This is using PHP.**

**Edit: Thanks for the help in the comments!  If someone could summarize the lessons learned & answer this, I will accept your answer.  I've taken the advice and completed the change in about 2 hours.**

Comment: Creating a table for each user would be considered absurd for most applications.

Comment: These tables store messages sent to the user.  They could be receiving hundreds, and there could be thousands of users.

Comment: Why do you need to create the table as the other user? Also: This is what indexes are good for. You can look up billions of rows in a short time using indexes

Comment: Psi So that if one user account is hacked, the other db user is hopefully secure.  Most recommend this type of compartmentalization.

Comment: If an account is hacked, how does it grant access to the database for that user? Do you want them to connect to mysql directly? If your application is secure, every user would see only the messages that relate to him anyway.

Comment: Not if a user account is hacked, if a mysql user account is (the ones php is using)

Comment: Creating thousands of tables is like keeping your database on a piece of paper.  It works, it's clunky, and NO ONE WOULD DO THIS.  Create 1 table and create an index on the users foreign key.  Also  making 1 table per username can open you to SQL injection attacks

Comment: I cleanse all user data and use prepared statements at the moment.

Comment: Unless you are writing a phpMyAdmin-like app, you are doing it wrong

Comment: *"Not if a user account is hacked"* --- *"I cleanse all user data and use prepared statements at the moment."* --- 1) Are you using a safe password hashing method? 2) You're using a prepared statement; great. Back to point #1 then. If so, how would your user base get hacked?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am using the PASSWORD_DEFAULT in PHP7.x with the recommended settings.  If someone could keylog/otherwise hack a password to the database.  Maybe by gaining FTP access

Comment: Btw, if you're going to address someone else directly, do as I did for you here like... @Bobdabiulder some may no longer be present in the question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Like this?

Comment: *"Maybe by gaining FTP access"* - Then that'd be because of too weak a password either set by your hosting provider or yourself. The question is too broad also. @Bobdabiulder Edit: Yes, like that.

Comment: Also: If the db-user your app is using is being hacked, the attacker would have access to all these tables anyway (if that user is allowed to do at least anything in that database). Again: Your approach will impact performance drastically (looking up the table name takes longer than looking up for a user id in one table if correctly indexed)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ight.  I think i got it now.  One database.  Two tables: users & messages.  Linked by foreign key.

Comment: Correct. `Entity Relation`, `Normalized`. Read, understand and apply this, and you will be happy with the results

Comment: @Bobdabiulder Yep, that's the ticket ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-  Please submit this as an answer & I will accept it for full credit ;)

Comment: @ all / if an answer is to be submitted, IMHO it should be a community wiki.

Comment: Your design seems absurd, but still, what do you want to achieve? Make your `CREATE` statements work? Put it all in a transaction and rollback the insert?

Comment: @Fred-ii- How does that work?  It'd be cool if it becomes community wiki.  These comments are a lesson in DB design/architecture

Comment: @simon.ro ideally, the thing would either fail or retry if only  one of the two operations completed.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It would be nice to have an answer so this could be marked as closed and not waste people's time so much